# Can dogs have cat allergy?

Tags: dogs, cats, allergies

I know cat allergy is quite common in human beings, how about dogs ? Will dogs also suffer from cat allergy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allergies are overreactions of the immune system. They're not necessarily caused by viruses or bacteria. As such it really depends on the kind of allergy as well as the individual pet.

So, in short: **No, unlikely. Possible, but not necessary.**